# Trusting Sell-Side Analysts and their ratings

Tags: stock-analysis, broker

I was wondering what percent of stocks are rated as a buy by the sell-side analysts and if they really mean anything. I feel like there sometimes can be a conflict of interest if the company does work with the firm that the analyst works at.

It seems fishy to me especially since during the fall of MoviePass (HMNY), sell-side guys gave it a buy rating while the buy side knew it was going to tank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analysts have relationships with company executives, giving them the ability to line up private meetings for large clients.  Much of their pay comes as a result of this corporate access and therefore, they avoid sell ratings so they can maintain those relationships.

About 5% of analyst  recommendations on  S&P 500 stocks are on the sell side, varying  modestly year to year.  This was true even in the years surrounding during the Internet Bubble in 2000 and the Global Financial crisis in 2008. Some brokers even avoid using the word 'sell' and in turn say underweight.

Comment: You just answered the fraction of the question that was on topic. Nicely done. I will encourage OP to edit out the part that veers off topic.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I answered the part of the question that I  know a little bit about and when it comes to HMNY, it's nothing.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Which part veers off topic? Ill edit it out right away. Thanks

Comment: I would just delete the last paragraph. Asking for a link to a reference like that is pretty off-topic.

Comment: I can't source it but some time ago I came across a chart that graphed what percent of stocks have sell signals on them, by year.  It might have been S&P 500 stocks but I don't remember.